# PHPUnit and VIM

Tags: php, vim, phpunit

I'm trying to run phpunit tests in VIM. Because I didn't found any useful plugins I decide to put a simple line in my .vimrc

```
autocmd FileType php noremap <Leader>x :w!<CR>:!phpunit %<CR>
```

The problems is that I get

```
shell returned 255
```

Insted of the results of PHPUnit.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `255` means "exit status out of range". You should check PHPUnit's doc about that. Maybe it needs specific conditions or arguments?

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin for this: [PHPUnit runner for Vim](https://github.com/joonty/vim-phpunitqf).